# Unable to propose tag wiki

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tag-wiki

I am trying to create a tag wiki for [question-of-the-week](/questions/tagged/question-of-the-week), but every time I click on **<kbd>Propose Tag Wiki</kbd>** it just reloads the page and doesn't let me make the tag wiki.

Comment: +1 Confirmed, I have this for almost any tag...

Comment: It seems to work fine on SU, just not on Meta.SU

Comment: This is unrelated to Javascript and only on Meta.SU, example redirect: http://meta.superuser.com/edit-tag-wiki/163. Indeed, that's what I meant, corrected...

Comment: +1 confirmed, doesn't work for a diamond mod as well...

Comment: Probably gets propagated from Meta.SO

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We're not currently allowing tag wikis to be edited on metas, as we plan to push out the shared meta tag wikis from meta.so.

This may change in the future.

Comment: That's logical, but then shouldn't the UI not be suggesting that I create a tag wiki if that can't be done?

Comment: what is the procedure if we want to have info for tags which are relevant just to SU? I understand the reasons for pulling tag data from the main meta site, but some tags are specific to a particular meta. At the very least, moderators should have the ability to edit tag wikis if the tag does not exist or has no wiki on meta.SO.

Comment: @Jeff, status on this?

Answer (score 0):

[Waffles says:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/121066/133693)

> Works now, you can edit any wikis on per-site metas, including the ones sourced from this meta.