# Meta Tag Wikis Can't be Edited

Tags: support, tag-wiki, meta-tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unable to propose tag wiki](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/2362/unable-to-propose-tag-wiki)

With the addition of tag wiki proposals, it seems as though Meta's language changed despite still not being able to edit tag wikis.
[image: Missing Edit Button]

I can see how that is beneficial from a maintainability standpoint for Meta, but the text is still there...mocking me...like that wretched blinking cursor in Word...

Comment: see also: http://meta.literature.stackexchange.com/questions/130/cannot-create-a-tag-wiki

Comment: Perhaps this should be reposted as a bug at [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Meta Tag Wikis are [derived](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/2362/unable-to-propose-tag-wiki) from Tag Wiki over at  [Meta.StackOverflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com).

You'll have to suggest edits there to have it populated here.